# How to query (price) information for multiple in-app products at once?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play

In Android in app billing is it possible to somehow query (price) information for all products using one query? Optimally you could pass in the product IDs and it would return information for those.

What I'm looking for is the SKProductsRequest equivalent for Android Market. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKProductsRequest/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/SKProductsRequest

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is possible now with Billing API v3. You can get information with [`getSkuDetails()`](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html#getSkuDetails) method. Example is [here](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html#QueryDetails).

```
ArrayList skuList = new ArrayList();
skuList.add("premiumUpgrade"); 
skuList.add("gas");
Bundle querySkus = new Bundle();
querySkus.putStringArrayList("ITEM_ID_LIST", skuList);

Bundle skuDetails = mService.getSkuDetails(3, getPackageName(), "inapp", querySkus);

int response = skuDetails.getInt("RESPONSE_CODE");
if (response == 0) {
    ArrayList responseList = skuDetails.getStringArrayList("DETAILS_LIST");

    for (String thisResponse : responseList) {
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(thisResponse);
        String sku = object.getString("productId");
        String price = object.getString("price");
        if (sku.equals("premiumUpgrade")) {
            mPremiumUpgradePrice = price;
        } else if (sku.equals("gas")) { 
            mGasPrice = price;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank u so much for the post, it works! But I have a question: does getSkuDetails() return the localized currency, or the developer's set of default price, which is in U.S. dollars? It seems to me, it only returns U.S. dollar, regardless I have set my system and google play account to be France. Do you know where would this be documented? I could not seem to find sufficient docs for this.

Comment: @sammiwei Sorry, I don't know.

Comment: `price_currency_code` gives the currency in the skuDetails bundle

Answer (score 1):

The Google example snippets (like https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html#QueryDetails) and other snippets I saw did not fit my usage. I either need to have an `inventory` instance or an `mHelper` (which is the IAB Helper). Looks like the question's upvote number is bigger than the accepted answer's upvote, so I'm not alone. My usage is similar to the TrivialDrive Example (https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/blob/master/TrivialDrive/), so let's look at that.

In the `MainActivity` `onCreate` there's a call for `queryInventoryAsync`:

```
    mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
        public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Setup finished.");
            ...

            // IAB is fully set up. Now, let's get an inventory of stuff we own.
            Log.d(TAG, "Setup successful. Querying inventory.");
            try {
                mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mGotInventoryListener);
            } catch (IabAsyncInProgressException e) {
                complain("Error querying inventory. Another async operation in progress.");
            }
        }
    });
```

In the listener you gonna have the inventory instance.

```
IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mGotInventoryListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
    public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Query inventory finished.");
        ...
        Log.d(TAG, "Initial inventory query finished; enabling main UI.");
    }
};
```

My problem is that my in-app products are consumable, and I'd like to query the details for *all* of my products in the beginning whether the user already bought some or not. For example I want to know the price of all the products expressed in the local currency instead of just USD, so the user is informed before already engaging too much into the purchase. Normally `queryInventory` only gives back what the user already purchased / handled (either consumable or non consumable products, subscriptions, ...).

If you are in the same shoes (want to know all details at the start) what you need to do is two fold:

1. You need to call a polymorph variant of the `queryInventoryAsync` within the `mHelper.startSetup` where you can instruct.
2. In the listener you'll be able to iterate over your SKUs and see the details.

So the **first**:

```
String[] SKUS = { SKU_1, SKU_2, SKU_3, SKU_4, SKU_5 };  // products
...
mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(true, Arrays.asList(SKUS), new ArrayList<String>(), mGotInventoryListener);
```

The second parameter here is the product SKUs, the third (I'm not using here) is the subscription SKUs.

**Second**: Then within the `QueryInventoryFinishedListener` now you have all of them in the `inventory` and you can iterate over your SKUs:

```
        for (String sku: SKUS) {
            SkuDetails skuDetails = inventory.getSkuDetails(sku);
            String price = skuDetails.getPrice();
            ((android.widget.TextView)findViewById( *sku's ID* )).setText(price);
        }
```

Hope this helps. Soon I need to upgrade to a non AIDL based solution.